# Trying to understand scope on angular 5 .then

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, google-api-js-client, google-client-login

On this example, the promise that i created works ok.

But the promise from the google api don't work.

It says that the `this.youtube` is undefined

*index.html*
   `<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>`

*app.component.html*

```
<button (click)="customClick()">custom Promise</button>
<hr>

<hello name="{{ youtube }}"></hello>
<button (click)="youtubeClick()">youtube Promise</button>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {  } from '@types/gapi.client.youtube';
import {  } from '@types/gapi.auth2';


export class AppComponent  {

  name = 'Angular 5';
  youtube = 'youtube';

  egPromise(){
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function(){
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  customPromise(){
    this.egPromise().then( () => {
      this.name = 'from .then angular 5'
    });
  }

  customClick(){
    this.customPromise();
  }
/****************************************************/

youtubePromise(){
  gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: 'key',
        clientId: 'id',
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
        discoveryDocs: [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest"
        ]
        }).then(() => {
      this.youtube = 'from .then youtube'
    });
}

youtubeClick(){
  gapi.load('client:auth2', this.youtubePromise);
}
```

### Edit: Solution/Explanation

With the help of @vivek-doshi

I found this post searching "bind this"

https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/

And as the post explain

"it’s not always clear what this is going to refer to in your code, especially when dealing with callback functions, whose callsites you have no control over."

Since I'm working with the google API and i have no control over that code.

"This is because when the callback to the promise is called, the internal context of the function is changed and this references the wrong object."

And the function to load the library use a callback function, and don't even crossed my mind that the first callback was the problem.

So using the ES2015 Fat Arrows function, as the post says.

"they always use the value of this from the enclosing scope." ... "Regardless of how many levels of nesting you use, arrow functions will always have the correct context."

So instead of creating `binding` and `self` and `that` and `wherever`, I think that is more clean the use of `=>`

Other thing that it was confunsing me is that the google api aks for a callback with no argument.

So if you try to use
`const that = this;
gapi.load('client:auth2', this.start(that) );`

It will complain.

But using  `gapi.load('client:auth2', () => this.start() );` I'm not passing an argument.

This things could be simple for a lot of people, but since I'm learning, I will try to make it simple for others that are learning too.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code here

Comment: sorry, posted the wrong link, now it's ok

Comment: Still, you should post all relevant parts here for future viewers as the link may go down. In addition, you are very welcome to post the link for people to play around with it, but everything needed to answer your question should be here on StackOverflow

Comment: Helpful reading about `this`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: @daniel-hilgarth it's possible to post angular 5 project here? The code snippet only has 1.2.23

Comment: @MateusSilva: No, and you are not supposed to. You should post the *relevant parts* of your code. It's not necessary to be able to RUN here on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are losing the scope of `this` by calling :

```
gapi.load('client:auth2', this.youtubePromise);
```

Change above code to :

```
gapi.load('client:auth2', () => this.youtubePromise()); // ES6 Way
// OR
gapi.load('client:auth2', this.youtubePromise.bind(this)); // Traditional old way of doing
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-this-scope)**

Comment: ok, so this worked `gapi.load('client:auth2', () => this.youtubePromise());` but i don't completely understand why. can you point something to read about it, because I don't even know what to search, I did a lot of research before posting and don't came across any code similar to that.

Comment: @MateusSilva , this kind of issue happens most of the react side , on time of event binding , you can search via react if you want to get something more about this , for more details just google `binding this`

Comment: @MateusSilva , will you please also accept the answer also :)

Comment: I will, but I gonna try to edit the post and put more useful information about the problem and the answer. thanks @vivek-doshi

Comment: @MateusSilva , Thanks , Happy Coding BTW :)

Answer (score 1):

`this` is always the object the method is called on. However, when passing the method to then(), you are not calling it! The method will be stored somewhere and called from there later.

If you want to preserve this, you you need to preserve this before:

```
var that = this;
// ...
.then(function() { that.method() })
```