# Typescript "this" instance is undefined in class

Tags: angular, typescript

I found this and online and now trying to put it in TS.

Running the following throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'toggle' of null`

```
@Injectable()
export class HomeUtils {
    private canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
    private context;
    private toggle = true;

    constructor() { }

    public startNoise(canvas: HTMLCanvasElement) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.resize();
        this.loop();
    }

    private resize() {
        this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    }

    private loop() {
        this.toggle = false;
        if (this.toggle) {
            requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
            return;
        }
        this.noise();
        requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
    }

    private noise() {
        const w = this.context.canvas.width;
        const h = this.context.canvas.height;
        const idata = this.context.createImageData(w, h);
        const buffer32 = new Uint32Array(idata.data.buffer);
        const len = buffer32.length;
        let i = 0;

        for (; i < len;) {
            buffer32[i++] = ((255 * Math.random()) | 0) << 24;
        }

        this.context.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

I'm lost.

Comment: can you elaborate on how did you get the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49314827/trying-to-understand-scope-on-angular-5-then/49314984?noredirect=1#comment85631835_49314984

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Methods do not capture `this` and are dependent on the caller to call them with the correct `this`. So for example:

```
this.loop() // ok
let fn = this.loop;
fn(); // Incorect this
fn.apply(undefined) // Undefined this
```

Since you pass `loop` to another function `requestAnimationFrame` you need to ensure that `this` is captured from the declaration context and not decided by `requestAnimationFrame` :

You can either pass an arrow function to `requestAnimationFrame`

```
private loop() {
    this.toggle = false;
    if (this.toggle) {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop());
        return;
    }
    this.noise();
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop());
}
```

Or you can make loop an arrow function not a method:

```
private loop = () => {
    this.toggle = false;
    if (this.toggle) {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
        return;
    }
    this.noise();
    requestAnimationFrame(this.loop);
}
```

The second approach has the advantage of not creating a new function instance on each call to `requestAnimationFrame`, since this will be called a lot, you might want to go with the second version to minimize memory allocations.

Comment: Ok, this was gonna trouble me I see, thanks proper expl.

Comment: What if my `loop()` function has a `time` argument: `loop(time: number)`?

Comment: "Methods do not capture this" -- what a great language

Answer (score 9):

It's the call to `requestAnimationFrame`. You are passing a function not bound to a context, and so, inside that call to `loop` there is no `this`.

Change the call to:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => this.loop());
```

Arrow functions, contrarily to normal functions, are bound to `this`.